# XLS Files Renamed in Python Getting Corrupted?

Tags: python, xls, file-rename

I'm new-ish to Python and I'd like to accomlish a simple task but I'm a little stuck/confused. I simply have a task I'd like to automate, which is appending the current date to the filename of an excel file for work.

```
import os
import sys
import datetime


src_dir = os.path.normpath('\\\\EXAMPLE_SERVER_NAME\\x$\\Clients\\Public\\')
dir = os.listdir(src_dir)
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
date = str(month) + '.' + str(day) + '.' + str(year)
new_filename = ''

for filename in dir:
    if filename.startswith('MJ_ProdMaster'):
        str_index = filename.index('.',0,len(filename))
        new_filename = filename[:(str_index)] + ' ' + str(date) + '.xls' 
        new_filename = os.path.join(src_dir, new_filename)
        old_filename = os.path.join(src_dir, filename)
        os.rename(old_filename,new_filename)
```

When I open up the freshly renamed XLS file in Libre Office the warning I receive is:

> The file is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened. LibreOffice can try to repair the file.
>
> The corruption could be the result of document manipulation or of structural document damage due to data transmission.

So my renaming of the file has clearly corrupted it, even though superficially it seemed to rename files correctly. I am not sure exactly HOW I have corrupted it though. A secondary (but equally important) question is what should I have done differently in my script, because I'm clearly not accomplishing the renaming task successfully.

Edit: If it is any additional info, when I try to repair the file within Libre Office the error **Read-Error: Unknown or unsupported Excel file format.**

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do something like change a `.xlsx` to `.xls`? I'm not sure what the difference is, but I've run into errors like this when I've done things like that.

Comment: Can you open the original file, before renaming?

Comment: You rename "MJ_ProdMaster*". Are there any files in the directory that start with MJ_ProdMaster but are  not .xls files? If so, you added the .xls extension, but its invalid.

Comment: Ah god it is always something so simple that never gets noticed! Thank you @BenDundee I stupidly didn't notice I was renaming XLS to XLSX.

Comment: For generating the date string, just do `date = now.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')`.

Comment: @RolandSmith that is much cleaner than how I am doing it, thank you for that tip.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
new_filename = filename[:(str_index)] + ' ' + str(date) + '.xls'
```

try

```
new_filename = filename[:(str_index)] + ' ' + str(date) + filename[(str_index):]
```

This will maintain any previous suffixes, and will be fault-tolerant for multiple `.` characters in the file name.

Answer (score 2):

User BenDundee correctly guessed I was accidentally renaming an XLSX file to XLS and couldn't see what was right in front of my face.

Comment: I did! I meant to upvote because it was a useful addition to the script thanks :)

Comment: And the only reason I know is that I do this kind of thing all the time!